# Is this volume closed or opened

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'm trying to use the divergence theorem over a cylinder and I can't figure out if my cylinder is opened or closed, to know if I have to add the bottom and the top of the cylinder in my integral to use the divergence theorem...

I have the following equations : $x²+y²=1;0≤z≤2$

Comment: Your equations describe the surface of a cylinder. But the circles at the bottom and at the top are not included.

Comment: But why are those not included? I have $0≤z≤2$ not $0<z<2$ ? Can you write the equations where the circles at the bottom and at the top are included ? Thanks.

Comment: For example the point $(0,0,0)$ is not included.

Comment: The volume of your cylinder is $x^2+y^2\le 1$ with $0\le z \le 2$, so the cup is $x^2+y^2 \le 1$ for $z=2$.

Comment: This has nothing to do with "open" and "closed" sets  in the sense of general topology.  The essential point is the following: The divergence theorem is about a three-dimensional body $B$ and its full boundary $\partial B$. The latter is a closed surface, maybe consisting of several pieces sewn together along edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete surface can be expressed as:

$$
x^2+y^2= 1 \quad 0 < z < 2 
$$
for the cylindrical surface, and

$$
x^2+y^2 \le 1 \quad z=0 \;\lor\; z=2
$$
for the two 
basis.

Answer (score 0):

The cylinder in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is closed. Look at the classical definition of closed sets, a set which contains all its limit points. Try and convince yourself that the set you described is indeed closed in that manner.

Comment: Ok the surface is closed but the bottom and the top are not included no? Thats what Im trying to understand to use for the divergence theorem.